# Page refresh on clicking checboxlist in repeater

Tags: asp.net, postback, repeater, checkboxlist

I am annoyed with a problem I have repeater control in updatepanel like this.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdPnlConstituentRepeater" ChildrenAsTriggers="true"    runat="server">

                            <ContentTemplate>
                                <asp:Repeater ID="repConstituentInformation" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="repConstituentInformation_ItemDataBound">
 <ItemTemplate>
 <asp:DropDownList ID="dropRegistrantDownCostType" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true"
                                                        AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="dropRegistrantDownCostType_SelectedIndexChanged"
                                                        EnableViewState="true">
                                                        <asp:ListItem Text="Select Type" Value="0" Selected="True" />
                                                    </asp:DropDownList>

 <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkBoxListRegistrantBenefits" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server"
                                                        OnSelectedIndexChanged="chkBoxListRegistrantBenefits_SelectedIndexChanged">
                                                    </asp:CheckBoxList>
</itemTemplate>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

The problem I face that whenever I select any value from dropdown all the page gets refreshed After spending hours on the google I found a solution i.e, on itemdatabound event of repeater we just need to add the following code after finding the dropdown,

```
Dim sm As ScriptManager = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page)
            sm.RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(objDropdownlist)
```

It worked very well for the dropdown but same is not working for checkboxlist like using the scripmanager instance if I write `sm.RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(chkBoxListRegistrantBenefits)`, it is not working :(

Comment: You have to specify a `<Triggers>` section in the update panel and declare your dropdown and checkbox as [AsyncPostBackTrigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.asyncpostbacktrigger.aspx)s.

Comment: @JimSchubert: That shouldn't be necessary, but it might still solve his problem.

Comment: Try adding `ClientIDMode="AutoID"` to the Repeater control. You should not have to add any triggers and you should not even have to call `RegisterAsyncPostBackControl`. The `ChildrenAsTriggers` should take care of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `ClientIDMode="AutoID"` to the Repeater control.

You should not have to add any triggers and you should not even have to call `RegisterAsyncPostBackControl`. The `ChildrenAsTriggers` should take care of that.

Comment: +1. This is interesting that `ClientIDMode` causes the asynchronous postbacks to act differently than in previous versions.  However, `ClientIDMode` is only available in ASP.NET 4.0 and wouldn't solve this issue in previous version of ASP.NET.

Answer (score 1):

on Repeater ItemDataBound event

use screiptmanager method RegisterAsyncPostBackControl

this.ScriptManager1.RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(
e.Item.FindControl("  put here your checkbox ID   "));

Answer (score 0):

Add this Before start of `<ContentTemplate>`:

```
<Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="objDropdownlist" EventName="OnSelectedIndexChanged" />
</Triggers>
```

Comment: @Bhargav, please read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks. Unformatted XML markup is not visible and can make an answer impossible to understand.

Comment: I tried this way but got an error! 
The control collection cannot be modified during DataBind, Init, Load, PreRender or Unload phases

Comment: remove AutoPostBack="true" event because AsyncPostBackTrigger  do same thing.